# CloudWatch running Lambda task and does not restart process

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I don't know how to properly describe the trouble I'm having, but I'll show it to you.

I have a Lambda function designed to download a log of GPS buses positions and save them to S3.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import urllib.request

now = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=3, minutes=0)
datetimestamp = now.strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M")
print(datetimestamp)
bucket = "gps-onibus-rio-janeiro"  
s3folder = "schedules"
filename = "GPS" + datetimestamp + ".csv"
filepath = '/tmp/' + filename
baseURL = 'http://dadosabertos.rio.rj.gov.br/apiTransporte/apresentacao/csv/onibus.cfm'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(baseURL, filepath)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    key = s3folder + '/' + filename
    s3.upload_file(filepath,bucket,key)
```

It's working perfectly, then I created a CloudWatch rule to run it every five minutes. The problem is, it runs but keeps refering to the first file and it does not try to create a new file once the five minutes have passed. I'll show you the log.

```
220320201306
START RequestId: 4cc5df77-dfbb-45e9-85e9-31c6021446fb Version: 5
END RequestId: 4cc5df77-dfbb-45e9-85e9-31c6021446fb
REPORT RequestId: 4cc5df77-dfbb-45e9-85e9-31c6021446fb  Duration: 739.87 ms Billed Duration: 800 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 82 MB  Init Duration: 893.84 ms    
START RequestId: 3c76af58-0213-48dc-be77-912abb6212a3 Version: 5
END RequestId: 3c76af58-0213-48dc-be77-912abb6212a3
REPORT RequestId: 3c76af58-0213-48dc-be77-912abb6212a3  Duration: 251.99 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 84 MB  
START RequestId: 7dc6cb90-1551-4b9e-aee4-3a8df3ddf74b Version: 5
END RequestId: 7dc6cb90-1551-4b9e-aee4-3a8df3ddf74b
REPORT RequestId: 7dc6cb90-1551-4b9e-aee4-3a8df3ddf74b  Duration: 186.91 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 84 MB  
START RequestId: 8d68e7d1-9b44-4830-8e01-f6e33b150dc2 Version: 5
END RequestId: 8d68e7d1-9b44-4830-8e01-f6e33b150dc2
REPORT RequestId: 8d68e7d1-9b44-4830-8e01-f6e33b150dc2  Duration: 234.85 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 85 MB  
START RequestId: 8ae750c4-73c3-4425-90aa-653b0a1be6e8 Version: 5
END RequestId: 8ae750c4-73c3-4425-90aa-653b0a1be6e8
REPORT RequestId: 8ae750c4-73c3-4425-90aa-653b0a1be6e8  Duration: 184.37 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 85 MB  
START RequestId: 6c80cc04-f06e-43a9-8764-bdee41619b05 Version: 5
END RequestId: 6c80cc04-f06e-43a9-8764-bdee41619b05
REPORT RequestId: 6c80cc04-f06e-43a9-8764-bdee41619b05  Duration: 221.07 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 85 MB
```

Is there any way to force it to begin again after five minutes to create a new file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the filename construction code inside the handler.